# What directory do I put my Spotify apps in on Vista?

Tags: html, windows-vista, spotify

I'm trying to develop apps for Spotify using [their API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/). I started using [this guide of theirs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/) but got stuck quickly when it said to put my files in "My Documents/Spotify". Vista uses the folder Documents instead of My Documents (and if you try to create My Documents inside your user folder, it merges the contents into Documents), so I'm having trouble getting Spotify to find my apps.

I created folder "hurrdurrdurr" inside C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Spotify\, and put the HTML and JSON files described [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/) inside of C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Spotify\hurrdurrdurr\, but "spotify:app:hurrdurrdurr" gave me a "metadataFailed" message with "Error:appNotFound". Any ideas where I should be putting my app files?

And yes, all of the following things have happened:

- I have made my account a developer account
- The "Develop" tab has appeared in Spotify
- I have tried restarting Spotify after putting the app in the directory

Also, I'm using Spotify version 0.8.3.222.{build ID that I'm too lazy to copy}. I can't find a download link for any preview build, but this is the latest version as far as I can tell. Anyone

Answer (score 0):

The directory should be correct, in my case it is `C:\Users\buchetics\Documents\Spotify`. Something is probably wrong with your app. Check out the example/tutorial here:
https://github.com/mager/spotify-apps-tutorial

I just cloned the repository and it works with the same Spotify version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

After having a similar problem with getting the Spotify tutorial to load into Spotify on my Windows machine, I figured out what the issue was-- it's very simple.  I'm not going to claim this will resolve every issue but a lot of people who are using Windows based machines seem to be running into this issue.

1.Once you download the Spotify tutorial from github, extract it to the folder you've created-- as stated on the github site the folder should be "Spotify".

1. You can place the "Spotify" folder where ever you please as long as it's on the C: drive (Desktop, My Documents, etc).
2. Open the "Spotify" folder; then open the "apps-tutorial-master" folder-- within this folder is a folder with a similar name "apps-tutorial-master", cut all the files from within this folder and move them up to the parent of this folder and paste them.

   **"Spotify"->"apps-tutorial-master"->"apps-tutorial-master"->"THE FILES WE NEED TO MOVE UP ONE DIRECTORY"**;
3. The new directory structure should look like:

   **"Spotfy"->"apps-tutorial-master"->"THE FILES WE MOVED UP ONE DIRECTORY**;

Once you've cut and paste the files up one directory you should then be able to get Spotify to load the tutorials.  The redundancy in the folder structure comes from the extraction/unzipping by the windows utility.

I hope this helps those who are using a Windows machine.